# iphone 5 landscape media query not working

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

below media query not working. I have written this media query in **slider.php** page and included it in **index.php** page.

```
  //For iphone 5
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : landscape) 
{ 
    #mainslider
    {
        margin-bottom: 48px !important;
    }
}
<div id="mainslider" style="width:95%;margin:auto;height:150px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Clarify what you mean by not working? Does this breakpoint not work at all?

Comment: That means when I saw the code by inspect element, it didn't accept css media query for landscape means no media query exist for it. How it can be possible? What should be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or the site up somewhere? Its hard to answer without seeing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
I have changed only height of main slider to height: auto instead of margin-bottom. It is working now.

```
<div id="mainslider" style="width:95%;margin:auto;height:auto;">
</div>
```